# High refresh rate display stuck at 60Hz on laptop with hybrid GPU and advanced MUX switch

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution, nvidia-optimus

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my laptop (Lenovo Legion 7i 2022 IAX7).
The laptop uses a hybrid GPU configuration with NVIDIA's advanced optimus. The display is capable of running at 2560x1600@165.

After the installation, I installed the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and made sure that everything was up to date. However, my display is stuck at 60Hz while in Hybrid mode and running off of the iGPU (Intel UHD 770).

I tried running different `xrandr` commands to add a custom profile and tried setting it manually to 165. The output of that command shows the max refresh rate is 60 for the only resolution available.

I came across a reddit thread with someone having a similar problem with another laptop. One of the suggestions was disabling optimus and switching to the dGPU only mode. I did in the UEFI and sure enough, the display was running at 165Hz!
The next step that I followed was to extract the `edid.bin` file from the nvidia-settings app and moving it to `/lib/firmware/edid`. Then I modified `etc/defaults/grub` to include the following line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="drm.edid_firmware=eDP1:edid/edid.bin"`

(`eDP1` is the name of my display while connected to the iGPU, it's different when in dGPU-only mode)

After updating grub, I changed the mode to Hybrid again and my display was still stuck at 60Hz.

I would like to use the laptop in Hybrid mode as I don't really need the extra FPS gain and G-sync, not to mention the worse battery life.

Are there any possible solutions to this issue?

(I've tried that with Wayland, it does the same with the difference being that I have more resolutions and 60.01/59.99 refresh rates available)

I read from someone that it is a bug with NVIDIA optimus. I'm not sure how correct that is because I can't see how it'd affect the display when it's connected to the iGPU.

Thanks!

Comment: @nmath, I meant that mainly for games. I do care about the smoothness on the desktop. Also that is weird.. I have 165Hz when running from the iGPU on Windows with the Intel drivers installed so I don't know. I've heard some others experiencing the same issue but still couldn't find a solution. So I guess I'll have to resort to WSL to have the best of both worlds at least until I figure out how to fix it.